# Laravel accessing file uploads in nested arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to build a form that allows multiple file uploads and also allows repeatable form groups. The form group that can be repeated contains upload fields which can be dynamically added too e.g add another file functionality.

One thing I can't figure out is how I can access the uploaded files if they're nested in an array in the request i.e Request::file('upload'); won't work.

Here's an example of the HTML of the file input and you can see the level of nesting that's going on.

```
<input class="js-file-input" name="request[0][files[]]" type="file" />
```

The request index is incremented for each new form group that's added to build up a list of requests made by a user on the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @BarrayWalsh why don't you loop `Request::input('request')` and then process file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in my machine.

```
$inputs = Request::all();
var_dump($inputs);

    //prints
    array (size=2)
  '_token' => string 'jpY1dJy5t8' (length=40)
  'request' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'st2.jpg' (length=7)
      1 => string 'st2.jpg' (length=7)
```

Please try update your input field with following...

```
    <input class="js-file-input" name="request[0]files[]" type="file" />
    <input class="js-file-input" name="request[1]files[]" type="file" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't seem to work. I had tried it before and gave it another go to make sure I hadn't made a mistake but no luck. I was thinking since Request::all(); doesn't return the file input data that this would't work either but maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Let me try this at my machine

Comment: Cheers, appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for that. Not working and I'm just wondering do you have 'files'=> true on your form? Request:all() does return the name of the file the input's value without it but you can't upload the file without 'files'=> true

Comment: No i didn't enable files on this form, i was just trying to test submitted array. Please try changing name of input fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up in case anyone is trying to do somethnig similar.I've made some progress, one way I can access the files is by supplying array keys.

So $file = Request::file('request')[0]['files'] will return all the files for the first nested files array so I can loop through and save them. I reckon by checking if each array has files with something like hasFile should work. Doesn't really feel like the right way to do it but it looks like it's the only way at the moment.

I needed to update the file input HTML to this:

```
<input class="js-file-input" name="request[0][files][]" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can access the files is like this

```
$files = $request->request[0]['files'];
```